# How to replace multiple similar values with a single value

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Function SameStuff(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Boolean
    Dim bad As Boolean

    SameStuff = False
    ary1 = Split(Replace(s1, " ", ""), ",")
    ary2 = Split(Replace(s2, " ", ""), ",")

    Length1 = UBound (ary1)
    Length2 = UBound(ary2)

    k=1
    If Length1<= Length2 and Length1<>0 then
      for i=0 to Length1-1
        If ary1(i) = ary2(i) then 
          ary3(k,i) = ary1(i)
        End If
      Next i
      k=k+1
    else 
      Exit function
    End If
End Function
```

Here I take value from Range("A1") - (has 3 words) and value of Range("A2") - (has 4 words). Split them both by finding space between words and store them in arrays.  If length of one array is 3 and other is 4, 3 words from both the arrays will be compared. If 3 words are found to be same then Range("B1") and Range("B2") must both have the 3 word name i.e Range("A1").Value.  I think this logic will work fine to find similar names like "ABC DEF HIJ " in A1 and "ABC DEF HIJ Limited" in A2.

I am not able to put it in code.

Word length will not remain the same i.e 3,4 .

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the result, ary3?  Are you replacing the smaller 3 word cell with the longer 4 word cell if the first three words match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary would be an easy alternative, you can use the .exists method to do this for you, you have to transfer the array (result of split() ) to a dictionary tho, but that's a loop, not too tricky.  Or, you could leave one of the inputas as a string and split only 1, and use `if strStringLeftAlone like "* " & strSection(x) & " *"` or use instr, with the same idea as the search `" " & strSection(x) & " "` or find

Comment: @ Nathan Thanks a ton for suggesting Dictionary object . Was unaware of it till you mentioned. code works fine now

Answer (score 1):

This should work regardless how long the arrays are, i.e. no matter how many words (and spaces) there are in each of the strings to be compared. Notice I removed the `k` variable as it didn't seem to serve any purpose in the code. This solution does presuppose, however, that ONLY the LAST word in the two strings is different.

```
Public Function SameStuff(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Boolean

    Dim sameBool As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, Length1 As Long, Length2 As Long
    Dim tempArr1 as String, tempArr2 as String
    Dim ary1 as Variant, ary2 as Variant

    ary1 = Split(Replace(s1, " ", ""), ",")
    ary2 = Split(Replace(s2, " ", ""), ",")

    Length1 = UBound (ary1)
    Length2 = UBound(ary2)

   If Length1 <= Length2 and Length1 > 0 then

      For i=0 to Length1-1
         tempArr1 = tempArr1 & ary1(i)
         tempArr2 = tempArr2 & ary2(i)
      Next i

      If tempArr1 = tempArr2 then sameBool = True

   End If

   SameStuff = sameBool

End Function
```

**Edit**

Added some variable declarations to the code that I had forgotten, otherwise the code would not work with `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.